# ASPNETZERO - UI Template change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, aspnetboilerplate

My client does not like the Metronic UI provided in the ASPNETZERO template. He is looking into getting something custom designed by a UI/UX designer or purchasing another UI template. I wanted to find out if anyone else has done this change with ASPNETZERO and I wanted to ask some questions around this process.

- Have you completely removed Metronic template from ASPNETZERO
  and used another UI template?
- What challenges did you run into?
- How much effort did it take?

Any tips, tricks and advice that you can share on making this change would be much appreciated!

Comment: it'll take about 1 month to completely replace Metronic UI. Not hard but time consuming. There will be no problem while replacing. Currently aspnet zero team is doing the same thing (replacing metronic4 > metronic5. the both versions are completely different.)

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu - Would it be possible for the ASPNETZERO team to document the steps they are taking in removing Metronic 4? I think it would be huge help for your customers!

Comment: You can see their steps here: https://github.com/aspnetzero/aspnet-zero-core/compare/dev...metronic-v5

Comment: That GIT link is helpful, but I think if the ASPNETZERO team can create a document it would be really helpful. Many people have posted questions about the steps you need to take to change the UI in ASPNETZERO solution.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't done such a change myself, but as a user and UI/UX student, here are some tips:

> Have you completely removed Metronic template from ASPNETZERO and used another UI template?

- If you're completely replacing the UI with another template, you can easily remove Metronic UI. That's the great thing about [ASP.NET Zero](https://www.aspnetzero.com/Documents/Development-Guide-Core#solution-structure-layers) (and the underlying [ABP](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture))'s n-layered architecture.

> What challenges did you run into?

- Make sure that the UI template that the designer gives can actually be used with the data that you want to display from view models. **Tip 1**: Request that the designer considers the models.

> How much effort did it take?

- It will take a lot of effort binding the UI back to the view models and some models may change since a UX designer may propose a different flow. **Tip 2**: Request that the designer uses some form of view model, or template strings like `{Name}` for the hard-coded values in his design.
- **Tip 3**: Factor in time for ajax configuration, since the designer may only provide static screens.

Good luck!

---

**Update**

> Do you know all the files/folders I need to alter/remove or change in the ASPNETZERO solution?

The particular files depend on what you actually modify. The designer should provide you with `*.html` and  `*.css` files, maybe even `*.js` files. For the most part, you can leave the current `*.css` and `*.js` files (under `wwwroot`) alone. `*.cshtml` files (under `Views`) are safe to alter.

Comment: Thanks very much! Do you know all the files/folders I need to alter/remove or change in the ASPNETZERO solution?